# Change path of Hard drive

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, mount

Chances are that this question is already answered, however, I am unsure if the tutorials available **actually** solve my problem. Let me explain:

I have a HDD in my system with the following path:

`/media/username/02c18b8b-ae30-46d5-a351-b5525857XYZ`.

The last part of the path is rather hard to remember, so I wanted to change the location of my hardrive to simply

`media/mynewdrive/` or something similar.
My knowledge of mountpoints is limited, hence I was unsure if the tutorials actually answer my problem.

Any suggestions on how to do this? I believe my best bet is editing my fstab file, but thats beyond me. I have also tried using the 'Disks' GUI from the dash. However if I go to edit mount options, the mount point comes up as

`/mnt/02c18b8b-ae30-46d5-a351-b5525857XYZ`. Can I simply change this to what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Make a symlink:

```
ln -s /media/username/02c18b8b-ae30-46d5-a351-b5525857XYZ MediaNewDrive
```

Answer (score 0):

(Overmind posted his answer while I was composing my longer one.)

I'm sure there are fancy ways to cope with mountpoints, but maybe a simple symlink in your homedir (or wherever) will be enough for you:

```
ln -s /media/username/02c18b8b-ae30-46d5-a351-b5525857XYZ ~/mynewdrive
```

Notes:

- Final part of the original path is the partition UUID; it won't change unless you do some repartitioning etc., so you can rely on it.
- The solution doesn't need root access, it's hard to break your system with it.
- You can have many symlinks to single location (it's not that easy with `mount`); it is also easier to move or update a symlink than to reconfigure mountpoints.